# loop that passes each record in Table 2 and updates the new number according to Table 1

Tags: sql, sql-server

SQL
i need to write a procedure that converts an old number into a new one.
I have 2 tables:
1. conversion table - with 2 columns: old number and new number.
2. Table with all old numbers.

How do I make a loop that passes each record in Table 2 and updates the new number according to Table 1?

Comment: First please provide your table definitions, sample data and expected results.  Second, please provide what you've tried that is not working.  Third, you should think in sets rather than looping row by row when working in databases.  It's a very high likelihood that the solution you need does not involve a loop at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `UPDATE` statement will change all of the old values in Table2 that have matching new values in Table1.

```
UPDATE t2
SET OldValue = t1.NewValue
FROM
  Table2 AS t2
  JOIN
  Table1 AS t1
    ON t2.OldValue = t1.OldValue;
```

As noted in the comments, this is a set-based approach, not a loop.

Comment: but it is not working if t2 is a temporary table. you know why?

Comment: I can't duplicate that. Here's a [Rextester demo](https://rextester.com/TSMK97487). If you're still having issues, you should post a new question that includes more detail in order for us to help.